# Magento2.2 change admin user roles cant login

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, permissions, user-roles, admin-login

I have problem when change roles, all account of that roles can't access admin.

```
Step 1. User 1 will login as "CM" roles
Step 2. User 2 will update the resources available to role "CM"
Step 3. User 1 refresh page / login again.
Step 4. User 1 is unable to log in due to reset of role.
```

anyone meet that problem?

Comment: anyone help me?

Comment: I had the same experienced with the said issue, what I did to fix it is to mount again a fresh database in my local. I did some research and could not get any fix for this one. That was my last resort